# Figuring out the right proportion that resolves to a quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question:**

Two travelers A and B set out from two places, Γ and Δ, and at the same time; A from Γ with a design to pass through Δ, and B from Δ to travel the same way: after A had overtaken B, they found on computing their travels that they had both together traveled 30 miles; that A had passed through Δ four days before, and that B, at his rate of traveling, was a journey of nine days distant from Γ. Required the distance between the places Γ and Δ.

Answer: 6 miles.

**My thoughts:**

Considering previous problems in this chapter of the book, I need to make the right proportion that would lead me to a quadratic equation where $x=6$ is the required distance between the places.

I found that $x=30-2B$, where $B$ is the distance traveler B traveled.
Then, $B=\frac{30-x}{2}$ miles.

$A$ traveled $30 - \frac{30-x}{2}=\frac{30+x}{2}$ miles.

The speed of $B=\frac{30+x}{2\times9}=\frac{30+x}{18}$, the speed of $A=\frac{30-x}{2\times4}=\frac{30-x}{8}$

At this point I need to make the right proportion, which I have difficulties with...

Comment: It’s better to use \cdot or \times instead of * for multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notions, we have that $$x=B\cdot (9-\frac{30}{A+B}),\tag1$$

because $\frac{30}{A+B}$ is the time they travelled, so $9-\frac{30}{A+B}$ days were spent by the second traveler to get from $\Gamma$ to $\Delta$. Putting $A=\frac{30-x}8$ and $B=\frac{30+x}{18}$ in $(1)$, we get

$$x= \frac{30+x}{18}\cdot (9-\frac{30}{\frac{30-x}8+ \frac{30+x}{18}}).$$

I’ll leave it to you to find the roots of this equation, there are two of them: $6$ and $150$. Another question for you: why isn’t $150$ a second solution to the problem?

All that being said, I would solve the problem differently. I would denote the time from the start till the meeting as $t$. Then the following three equations hold:

$$\begin{cases}
t(A+B)=30\\
4A=tB\\
A(t-4)=B(9-t)\\
\end{cases}$$

Three equations, three unknowns. Here is the answer: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+%7Ba%28t-4%29%3Db%289-t%29%2C+4a%3Dtb%2C+t%28a%2Bb%29%3D30%7D). Again, there are two solutions. Why only one of them is good?

Then $x=A(t-4)=6.$